# No defination for Entry?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

(.Net 3.1, Entity Framework Core 3.1)

In the documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#saving-single-entities, it implements an InsertOrUpdate.

```
public static void InsertOrUpdate(BloggingContext context, Blog blog)
{
    var existingBlog = context.Blogs.Find(blog.BlogId);
    if (existingBlog == null)
    {
        context.Add(blog);
    }
    else
    {
        context.Entry(existingBlog).CurrentValues.SetValues(blog); // Error: Entry
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, `Entry` cannot be found for EF-Core 3?

Comment: Is this a compile error or runtime error? what is the exact error message? because `Entry` exists if you have a reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` package

Comment: `Entry` method [is there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.entry?view=efcore-3.1#applies-to)